# BeautifulSoup timing out on instantiation?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm just doing some web scraping with BeautifulSoup and I'm running into a weird error. Code:

```
print "Running urllib2"
g = urllib2.urlopen(link + "about", timeout=5)
print "Finished urllib2"
about_soup = BeautifulSoup(g, 'lxml')
```

Here's the output:

```
Running urllib2
Finished urllib2

Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/pspieker/Documents/projects/ThePyStrikesBack/tests/TestSpringerOpenScraper.py", line 10, in test_strip_chars
        for row in self.instance.get_entries():
      File "/Users/pspieker/Documents/projects/ThePyStrikesBack/src/JournalScrapers.py", line 304, in get_entries
        about_soup = BeautifulSoup(g, 'lxml')
      File "/Users/pspieker/.virtualenvs/thepystrikesback/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 175, in __init__
        markup = markup.read()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 355, in read
        data = self._sock.recv(rbufsize)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 588, in read
        return self._read_chunked(amt)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 648, in _read_chunked
        value.append(self._safe_read(amt))
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 703, in _safe_read
        chunk = self.fp.read(min(amt, MAXAMOUNT))
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 384, in read
        data = self._sock.recv(left)
    timeout: timed out
```

I understand that the `urllib2.urlopen` could be causing problems, but the exception occurs in the line instantiating BeautifulSoup. I did some googling but couldn't find anything about `BeautfiulSoup` timeout issues.

Any ideas on what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `urllib2` part that causing the timeout.

The reason you see it is failing on the `BeautifulSoup` instantiation line is that `g`, [the file-like object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen), *is being read by `BeautifulSoup` internally*. This is the part of the stacktrace proving that:

```
File "/Users/pspieker/.virtualenvs/thepystrikesback/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 175, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
```

Comment: Huh, so the `urllib2.urlopen` object doesn't throw an exception when instantiated?

Comment: @user2740614 nope, it would get triggered when `read()` is called on it..

Comment: Okay, that explains why it doesn't work. If you don't mind, why would you design `urllib2.urlopen` like that? Wouldn't you want it to fail faster (i.e. on instantiation)? Just curious :)

Comment: @user2740614 well, connection is made when you call `urlopen()` and it can throw `IOError` if it cannot connect to the host. But, in this case it can and is timing out when reading the response. You can read the response before explicitly: `g = urllib2.urlopen(link + "about", timeout=5).read()`.